# Dll injector don't works for x64 processes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll-injection

I have a code and I want inject a dll file into x64 process, but this code don't works, even if compile this for 64 Bits plattform.

Someone can help me with this please?

Any suggestion will welcome.

Here is my complete code and is compiling perfectlly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "injector.h"

using namespace std;
typedef TCHAR *PTCHAR;

BOOL GetPrivileges();

bool Injector::InjectDll(DWORD processId, std::string dllPath)
{
    HANDLE hThread, hProcess;
    void*  pLibRemote = 0;  

    HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandleA("Kernel32");

    char DllFullPathName[_MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathNameA(dllPath.c_str(), _MAX_PATH, DllFullPathName, NULL);
    printf("Loading dll: %s\n", DllFullPathName);

    GetPrivileges();

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);

    char szLibPath[_MAX_PATH];
    strcpy_s(szLibPath, DllFullPathName);

    pLibRemote = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(szLibPath), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (pLibRemote == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory, please restart with administrator privileges\n");
        return false;
    }

    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pLibRemote, (void*)szLibPath, sizeof(szLibPath), NULL);

    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "LoadLibraryW"), pLibRemote, 0, NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't load DLL");
        return false;
    }

    printf("Dll successfully loaded\n");

    return true;
}

DWORD GetPidFromName(PTCHAR processName)
{
  PROCESSENTRY32 proc32entry;
  proc32entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

  HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

  if(Process32First(snapshot, &proc32entry) == TRUE)
  {
    while(Process32Next(snapshot, &proc32entry) == TRUE)
    {
      if(_tcsicmp(proc32entry.szExeFile, processName) == 0)
      {
        CloseHandle(snapshot);
        return proc32entry.th32ProcessID;
      }
    }
  }

  CloseHandle(snapshot);

  return NULL;
}

BOOL GetPrivileges()
{
  HANDLE tokenHandle = NULL;
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokenPriv;

  if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &tokenHandle))
    return false;

  if(!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &tokenPriv.Privileges[0].Luid))
    return false;

  LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &tokenPriv.Privileges[0].Luid);
  tokenPriv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
  tokenPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

  return AdjustTokenPrivileges(tokenHandle, 0, &tokenPriv, sizeof(tokenPriv), NULL, NULL);
}


void RunApplication(LPCWSTR lpcszProc)
{

PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo; 
STARTUPINFO startupInfo; 
memset(&startupInfo,0, sizeof(startupInfo));
memset(&processInfo,0, sizeof(processInfo));

startupInfo.cb = sizeof startupInfo ;
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

if (CreateProcess(lpcszProc, NULL, NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInfo))
{
   WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
   CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
   CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
}
else
{
}

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

wchar_t dir[MAX_PATH] = {}; 
GetSystemDirectory(dir, MAX_PATH); 

wcscat_s(dir, L"\\");

StringCchCat(dir, MAX_PATH, L"notepad.exe"); 


    Injector inject;
    RunApplication(dir);
    Sleep(2000);
    DWORD processId = GetPidFromName(TEXT("notepad.exe"));
    inject.InjectDll(processId, "teste.dll");

system("pause");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

***Injector.h***

```
#ifndef INJECTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define INJECTOR_H_INCLUDED

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class Injector
{
public:
    /**
    * Loads a DLL into the remote process
    * @Return true on sucess, false on failure
    */
    bool InjectDll(DWORD processId, std::string dllPath);
private:
};

#endif // INJECTOR_H_INCLUDED
```

***Dll***

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        printf("base address: %X\n", (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL));

        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Does it work for a 32bit process? Have you noticed any errors when running for a 64 bit process? Does the function InjectDll run through properly and you get the message - "Dll successfully loaded"?

Comment: I already solved. `WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);` was my trouble.

Answer (score 0):

WaitForSingleObject does not return until after the child process exits

```
WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

^ this is causing it to wait until the process returns, meaning it exits

change that dwMilliseconds argument to 3000 to wait 3 seconds and then continue execution, this would be fine for most processes and solve your problem.